# Core Data: multiple entities related to a single entity

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an entity called 'SyncInfo' (including a UUID and a modified date) that I want other entities in my data model to have an instance of (i.e. employee/department).

Is there a simple way to get Core Data to allow me to do this without requiring that SyncInfo have relationships with every single one of the other entities in the data model? I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, I've only been doing Core Data stuff for a short while now.

Comment: This is a somewhat confusing question. You want the entity to have relationship with multiple entities in the first paragraph, but you want the entity not to have a relationship with multiple entities in the second paragraph. What is the problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: Good point. I mean to say I want some of the entities to contain an instance of SyncInfo but not require SyncInfo to have a zillion relationships to accommodate that. Will edit for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not required to have an inverse relationship from the SyncInfo entity back to any of the entities that have a relationship with SyncInfo.
Xcode will give you a warning about the missing inverse relationship which can be ignored.